# Some icon sizes showing massively huge in IntelliJ 2017.2

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

Can anyone explain why after doing a fresh reinstall of IntelliJ 2017.2, I getting these massively sized icons? It seems to be only some icons from plugins and Gradle. (None of the built-in or system icons are doing it.) I've checked my settings and nothing indicates a problem with the font size nor icon size. I've even compared my settings to another computer that is not having this issue and there is no variance, so I'm assuming it's a setting outside my IntelliJ. Anyone?

I'm running Ubuntu Mint 16.04 if that helps.

Comment: Do you face the same issue with new sample Gradle project? What JDK do you use to run IDEA?